# Is there a way to keep the frame range but skip first n frames

Tags: rendering, animation

Is there a way to have a frame range from i.e. `Frame Start 1` to `End 1000` but skip the first 400 Frames and start rendering the animation at frame 401 without changing the `Frame Start` value?

Why would I ever need this?

Unfortunately I started rendering a procedural animation, where some values depend on the values of `Frame Start` and `Frame End`. Blender crashed half way through rendering the frames and I want to resume at a specific frame. If I change the `Frame Start` now, I would get a totally different animation.

Comment: FYI if you disable "Overwrite" in the render settings, the frames that are already rendered in the target folder will not get re-rendered

Comment: Thats an even better solution for some cases. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this Add-on does what you need: [Loom](https://github.com/p2or/blender-loom/releases)

In your case you'd simply press Ctrl + Shift + F12 to bring up the render dialog. And then enter 401-1000.

Comment: Just tested this and works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Posting that answer for the sake of completeness, since it seems it would do the trick.

Disabling "Overwrite" in the render settings will prevent rendering the frames that have already been rendered in the animation, if they are still in the target folder.

[image]